# stack level too deep (SystemStackError) while deploy heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.3

I'm having a stack level too deep error using Ruby 2.3.1 with Rails 4.2.6.
How should I fix this problem?

When I run below command, error showed up.

```
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

Here is the error.

```
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    8390: from /app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
    8389: from /app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
    8388: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
    8387: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:120:in `with_friendly_errors'
    8386: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:123:in `rescue in with_friendly_errors'
    8385: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:45:in `log_error'
    8384: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:95:in `request_issue_report_for'
    8383: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/env.rb:18:in `report'
     ... 8378 levels...
       4: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       3: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       2: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       1: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Here is Gemfile.rb

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.8'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5', group: :development
gem 'pg', group: :production
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc



# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'compass-rails','~> 2.0'
  gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
  gem 'devise'
  gem 'omniauth'
  gem 'omniauth-facebook'
  gem 'omniauth-twitter'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'paperclip'
  gem 'omniauth-instagram'
  gem 'instagram'
  gem 'friendly_id'
  gem 'font-awesome-rails'
  gem 'zeroclipboard-rails'
  gem 'rails-i18n'
  gem 'google-analytics-rails'
  gem 'carrierwave'
  gem 'acts_as_paranoid', '~> 0.6.0'
  gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

I updated rails version to 4.2.8 from 4.2.6. but still having same problem.

And even, heroku run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` doesn't work.

Can't understand why still have this error.
Anyone help me?

Comment: can you post your `config/database.yml` file? Of course obfuscate any real credentials for security.  Also if you upgrade rails you need to run `bundle update`

Comment: Does `bundle exec rake db:rollback db:migrate` work locally?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error remove.
ruby version on production was 2.5.0 that is inappropriate. 
I had version down 2.4.5. from 2.5.0, then it works.